# Best way to get Guidance of the Avatar on a Factotum?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, optimization

I currently have a level 5 factotum with Knowledge Devotion and a bunch of skill points in Iajutsu Focus, and have just become aware of the spell [Guidance of the Avatar](https://www.wizards.com/dnd/article.asp?x=dnd/sb/sb20010504a). This looks like the perfect spell for a factotum- As a general rule, doing shiny things with knowledge is their specialty, and this is a fairly significant bonus. (It's an easy +3 attack and damage for the rest of the fight with Knowledge Devotion, or 4 dice worth of iajutsu focus.) If it was a wizard spell, no problem- I can cast wizard spells up to level two already, but alas, it's a cleric spell.

What is the optimal way to get access to this spell? (Besides asking your cleric buddy. No cleric in the party- though we do have a wizard.)

Bonus points for

- not requiring me to take levels in another class, especially one that might not synergize well with factotum. (I.E., cleric.)
- less resources committed to getting this. I.E., 20gp for an item is better than 200gp, one feat is better than three, etc.
- the more times I can use it per day.
- it being something I do, as opposed to asking the wizard or it being a magic item, though both are acceptable.

Comment: Are custom magic items allowed in your game?

Comment: Also, I suspect that in 3.5 this spell was overhauled as "Divine Insight" (a rather more balanced spell for your purposes, but subject to the same question.) Consider instead the bard/1 spell "Improvisation"

Comment: Custom magic items are allowed, but heavily scrutinized. The DM tends to think I char-op harder than I actually do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find anything besides magic items that do what you want. Nothing else reaches the bar you've set. It doesn't even appear official or 2nd-party feats can let a factotum use *guidance of the avatar* [div] ("Spellbook" [here](https://www.wizards.com/dnd/article.asp?x=dnd/sb/sb20010504a)). Consider adding the spell *guidance of the avatar* to your spell list so that employing wands of it are easier *via* 1 level of the cloistered cleric (*UA* 50) variant cleric; this gets decent skill points, and 3 Domains--or 2 Domains and, with the DM's permission, swap out the knowledge Domain (as per *CC* 52-3) to acquire the feat Knolwedge Devotion (*CC* 60) that way rather than spending your level-up feats.

**Magic Items**
These are listed in their possibility of approval. They start reasonable and get progressively more shady. Steel yourself for fights and recrimination if drawing from the bottom of the list. I am only *presenting* the information; the DM must determine if and how the following function in his game. Omitted are even more obvious sources of acquiring spellcasting (e.g. a *minor ring of spell storing* (*DMG* 233) (18,000 gp; 0 lbs.), an *ioun stone* (vibrant purple prism) (*DMG* 260) (36,000 gp; 0 lbs.))

- A *wand of guidance of the avatar* (2nd-level spell at caster level 3) (90 gp/charge; 0 lbs.). Consider a wand chamber (*Du* 30, 34) (100 gp; 0 lbs.) for your gnome quickrazor. Requires successful Use Magic Device skill checks. Requires only core (and a general splatbook for the wand chamber); the easiest way.
- A *minor schema of guidance of the avatar* (2,400 gp; 0 lbs.). You can learn more about *minor schema*, which are like 1/day scrolls, on *MoE* 122. Requires a setting-specific splatbook.
- A custom magic item, probably a helmet. Even a generous DM may say that an item capable of producing an effect like the spell *guidance of the avatar* at will is a bargain at 80,000 gp (it provides a +20 skill bonus, after all), especially for your character. The price might drop by pointing at the *crystal ball with true seeing* (*DMG* 253) (80,000 gp; 7 lbs.), which is far deadlier to campaigns than +20 to skill checks. Requires only core but needs DM approval.
- A *spellworm* (the 2nd-level Clr spell *guidance of the avatar* at caster level 3) (*Dragon* #343 80-1) (300 gp; 0 lbs.). The DM must house rule the *spellworm* (the description says that "casting the stored spell is a standard action" in one paragraph then in the next says that "the host casts the spell as a full-round action"--I'm not making that up). Essentially a potion without the potion's baggage, ingest many and more whenever you've a spare 300 gp--the power of *spellworms* apparently exists until expended. You'll have worms, though, and that's gross. Second-party material.
- A command word activated custom item of *guidance of the avatar*, probably a helmet. According to *DMG* 285 this has a base price of 2 (as a 2nd-level spell) x 3 (as a 3rd-level caster) x 1,800 gp (for a command word activated item) = 10,800 gp, and a market price of 21,600 gp. Requires only core but needs DM approval and is arguably underpriced.
- *+1 Tiny spell storing* (*DMG* 225) (+1 bonus) *arrows* (50) (8,300 gp 5 sp; 0.3 lbs.), each loaded with the spell *guidance of the avatar*, costing 60 gp per casting according to Spellcasting and Services (*PH* 129) for an extra 3,000 gp. Use them as improvised weapons to stab yourself and subsequently gain the spell's benefits. More expensive than a wand but avoids Use Magic Device skill checks. Whether the weapon special ability *spell storing* can be applied to ammunition is the subject of violent conflict. Broach this possibility only among good friends. Requires only core but needs DM approval.
- *+1 spell storing fukimi-bari* (3) (8,350 gp each; 1/10 lb. each) (*AE* 7) loaded with the spell *guidance of the avatar*, costing 60 gp per casting according to Spellcasting and Services. Attempt this only if your group accepts the previous. Put the 3 *+1 spell storing fukimi-bari* in your mouth, pause while other players crack wise, spit all 3 at yourself as an attack action, and gain the benefits of the spell *guidance of the avatar* thrice (*not* +60 but 3 separate activations). Requires an unupdated 3.0 splatbook and DM approval.
- A *knowstone* (*guidance of the avatar*) (*Dragon* #333 93) (4,000 gp; 0 lbs.). If the DM allows characters to employ the Use Magic Device skill to spend turn attempts they don't have to activate magic items (like Lidda does with the magic chalice on *PH* 86), he may allow characters to use spell slots they don't have to activate magic items. Not only does a *knowstone* "provide its bearer with knowledge of the inscribed spell" but also "he can then use his spell slots to cast [the inscribed spell] normally." Requires 2nd-party material and a potentially campaign-changing reading of the Use Magic Device skill.
- An automatically resetting boon trap (*Du* 136) of *guidance of the avatar* (approx. 3,120 gp) on your spell component pouch. Once per round as a free action that doesn't provoke attacks of opportunity trigger the trap by retrieving a spell component (I recommend a live spider (*PH* 283)). Requires a general splatbook but a host of DM interpretations, and the campaign implications of boon traps are stunningly far-reaching.

**The Spell Itself**
I can't imagine a class that *wouldn't* benefit from being able to use the 2nd-level Clr spell *guidance of the avatar* [div] ("Spellbook" [here](https://www.wizards.com/dnd/article.asp?x=dnd/sb/sb20010504a)). However, it's author might have a different definition of what makes a balanced spell than other writers do. The only other spell contribution the author's made that I can find is the spell *dirge of discord* [ench] ("Spellbook" [here](https://www.wizards.com/dnd/article.asp?x=dnd/sb/sb20010601a)), which in the link is a 5th-level Clr spell but was overhauled in *Complete Adventurer* on page 45 to a 3rd-level Brd spell (the updated version changes the original spell's ability to give affected creatures a *-8* penalty to Dexterity to a more reasonable -4 penalty to Dexterity). Also, the spell *guidance of the avatar* is 3.0 material, making it suspect at some tables, and wasn't included, like many older published-first-on-Wizards-Web-site spells were, in the *Spell Compendium*. It's an orphan spell, existing solely on that page, a relic of a past edition, never officially referenced again. In short, don't marry it yet--even a reasonable DM might not allow the spell *guidance of the avatar* into his game.

Answer (score 2):

<s>My suggestion is to get yourself an Eternal Wand or two of it. They're 4,420gp to buy one, and give two uses each per day.</s>

Because I'm a derp, I totally forgot that you can't put a divine spell on one normally. Finding an artificer might do the trick, or a mystic theurge with Alternate Spell Source, or a rainbow warsnake at high-level, or something else that gets cleric spells as arcane.

Alternatively, just use Minor Schemas. A 2nd-level spell on one is 2,400gp. A bit more expensive than Eternal Wands, but still alright.

Later on, you could possibly get Minor Schemas (from Magic of Eberron; they're 1/day uses of a spell on an item) of Quickened Guidance of the Avatar (spell level 6, so 26,400gp), for a nice +20 to your iaijutsu focus roll the moment you need it.

Comment: An *eternal wand* (*MIC* 159) specifies arcane spells. A summary of how *guidance of the avatar* got into an *eternal wand* would improve this answer.

Comment: Oh, that puts a damper on things. My bad, totally forgot. In that case, tracking down an artificer could work, since they should be able to do that.