# What methods are there to remove, prevent, or otherwise safeguard from penalties from Light Blindness?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Considering that most adventuring parties will deal with light, and there are a few good templates and races for stealthy types that include Light Blindness (or at least Light Sensitivity) what is out there to counteract this in someone who suffers from it?  I know of a few items that offer bonuses to saves against harmful light effects, but would these protect against Light Blindness/Sensitivity as well?  And what would be the best (price and effect wise) options to protect against Light Blindness?  And the best for Light Sensitivity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Minimizing Light Sensitivity & Light Blindness

**Both**

- Both light sensitivity and light blindness are mitigated by the feat **Daylight Adaptation** (*RoE* 108).

**Light Sensitivity**

- To ameliorate light sensitivity, use the alchemical item **sundark goggles** (*RDr* 122, 123) (10 gp; 0 lbs.), which say that

  > The smoked lenses of these goggles block light. They are typically fixed into a band of canvas that clasps together at the back to keep the goggles from falling off. Sundark goggles negate the dazzled condition experienced by a creature with light sensitivity while in bright illumination. As a side effect, they grant the wearer a +2 circumstance bonus on saving throws against gaze attacks. A creature wearing sundark goggles can’t use a gaze attack, since other creatures can’t see its eyes. Creatures without low-light vision or darkvision that wear sundark goggles take a –2 penalty on Search and Spot checks.
- If on a budget, light sensitivity can be ameliorated with **shaders** (*RoE* 103) (1 sp; 0 lbs.) which

  > are goggles of a sort that fit over an orc's eyes with a loop of leather tightened behind the ears. Made from a piece of wood or bamboo with a thin slot carved in it to see out of, shaders negate an orc's light sensitivity but impose a -1 penalty on Spot checks.

  Whether non-orcs gain any benefit from shaders is the DM's decision.

**Light Blindness**

- The 1st-level drow Domain spell ***cloak of dark power*** [abjur] (*SpC* 48) for 1 min./level  removes the creature touched's light blindness penalties and grants the creature touched a +4 bonus to saving throws *versus* light and darkness spells.
- The 2nd-level Sor/Wiz spell ***shadow shroud*** [evoc] (*DrU* 62-3) as an immediate action for 1 round/level grants the caster a +5 bonus to competence bonus to Hide skill checks in areas of darkness and negates the caster's penalties and other "harmful effects" due to the caster's light blindness and light vulnerability traits.

## Alternately: Minimize the symptoms

*Much* longer than this is the list of items and spells that prevent or mitigate blindness or dazzling in general: the *Raptor's Mask* (MIC), *Goggles of the Golden Sun* (MIC 205), or the spell *Vision of the Omniscient Eye* (DM 74). You'd still be Light Blind or Light Sensitive going down this route, but its effects would be minimized or negated.

Comment: Looks pretty good, any temporary options for a non-caster until I can get the feat or any items for Light Blindness?

Comment: You could argue with your DM that the [*shaders*](http://www.canadacool.com/COOLFACTS/QUEBEC/QUEBECPHOTOS/SnowGogglesA.jpg) should be good enough to make you Light-Sensitive instead of Light-Blind (at the cost of -1 Spot). It's not a complete recovery, but it's already better than nothing.

Comment: @Dorian There're all the standard ways to cram spells into [magic items](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/34324/8610), but I've found no specific items to mitigate light blindness.

Comment: Alrighty, thanks for looking into it at least.  I can probably figure something out in the event it becomes an issue before I can take the feat.

Comment: @Dorian I like the *Raptor's Mask* from the MIC. Renders the wearer immune to all blindness and dazzling, not just those from Light Blindness.

Comment: @Ernir Yeah, *much* longer than this is the list of items and spells that prevent or mitigate blindness or dazzling in general (e.g. the aforementioned *mask*, *goggles of the golden sun* (*MIC* 205), the spell *vision of omniscient eye* (*DM* 74)).

Comment: @HeyICanChan I figure it's worth mentioning that route, so I've amended it to the end of your answer. Please check to see if you're happy with the way I've written it, and edit or roll back as you please.

Answer (score 0):

MIC 75 Blindfold of true darkness | Blindsight out to 30 ft., immune to sight-based effects | 9,000gp
it makes you blind past 30ft which can be a problem out of combat but it does make you imune to gaze attacks too.

Tremorsense Items/Feats are useful for overcoming light blindness too.