# Items to enhance spot checks?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, skills

My character often has to make spot checks for various purposes, so I am considering trying to help myself with some magic tool to improve my spot checks.

But after a quick research in D&Dtools and in the [x stat to y bonus guide](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?125732-3-x-X-stat-to-Y-bonus), the only relevant item I found was [Hawk's Ointment](http://dndtools.eu/items/complete-adventurer--54/hawks-ointment--347/). I was expecting something better like some googles or lens or some lantern, or some generic tool giving bonuses on all wisdom related abilities, but did not found anything of these.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The skill [Spot](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/spot.htm) has [epic uses](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/epic/skills.htm#spot) and is useful to all but blind adventurers. It's one of those skills that if a character can he should put maximum ranks in it. But, even if he does, it's a good idea to have the skill *even higher*. I've drawn from a variety of sources in this list; abbreviations are available [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/36990/8610).

## Improving Spot Skill Checks with Spells

The *best* items for improving Spot skill checks are wands. A creature with a non-negative Charisma modifier and but 1 rank in the skill [Use Magic Device](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/useMagicDevice.htm) (*PH* 85-6) can make Use Magic Device skill checks to use a wand (DC 20) until he succeeds by rolling a 19 or 20 (or until he can't use the wand that day by rolling a 1) and improves markedly his chances of (eventual) success with minimal investment. The *real* key is finding the different kinds of bonuses to one's Spot check so all of those bonuses stack. Conveniently,<sup>1</sup> I've done that below.

- The 1st-level Drd spell ***raptor's sight*** [trans] (*RW* 175) for 1 hour/level grants the caster, among other benefits, a +5 competence bonus to Spot skill checks.
- The 1st-level Sor/Wiz spell ***eyes of the avoral*** [trans] (*BE* 99) for 10 min./level grants a touched creature a +8 racial bonus to Spot skill checks.
- The 1st-level Rgr spell ***embrace the wild*** [trans] (*SpC* 79) for 10 min./level grants the caster, among other benefits, a +2 bonus to Spot skill checks.
- The 3rd-level Sor/Wiz spell ***vision of the omniscient eye***<sup>2</sup> [div] (*DM* 74) for 1 min./level grants the caster, among other benefits, a +10 insight bonus to Spot skill checks.
- The 3rd-level herald spell ***eagle eyes*** [trans] (*Dragon Annual* #5 87), for 10 min./level, grants a touched creature, among other benefits, a +20 bonus to Spot skill checks.
- The 3rd-level meditation Domain spell ***that art thou*** [div] (*OA* Web enhancement "The Mahasarpa Campaign Setting: A Campaign Option Web Enhancement for *Oriental Adventures*" 8) for 1 round/level grants the caster, among other benefits, a +20 bonus to Spot skill checks.
- The 4th-level Drd spell ***essence of the raptor*** [trans] (*SpC* 84) for 10 min./level grants the caster, among other benefits, a +8 bonus to Spot skill checks.

This list, of course, ignores the myriad of ways spells can improve skills in general (e.g. the 1st-level Brd spell *improvisation* [trans] (*SpC* 121), the 2nd-level Clr spell *divine insight* [div] (*SpC* 70), the 2nd-level Clr spell [*guidance of the avatar*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/34324/8610) [div] (Spellbook column ["*Guidance of the Avatar*"](https://www.wizards.com/dnd/article.asp?x=dnd/sb/sb20010504a))).

This list also ignores the far rarer handful of ways to improve all of one's Wisdom-based skills--*including* the Spot skill--by toying with one's Wisdom (e.g. the 2nd-level Sor/Wiz spell [*owl's wisdom*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/owlsWisdom.htm) [trans] (*PH* 259), the 2nd-level Drd spell *animal spririt* [div] (*MoI* 98-99), the 5th-level Drd spell *owl's insight* [trans] (*SpC* 152), the 8th-level Sor/Wiz spell *necrotic empowerment* [necro] (*LM* 68)). Many are higher level effects, restricted not to wands but to scepters (*LE* 8) and even [staffs](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#craftStaff) (*PH* 92).

One of the biggest problems with making Spot skill checks is the massive and unreasonable -1 penalty per 10 ft. of distance (*PH* 83). It's likely the DM will waive this in many cases lest absurdity ensue, but if he doesn't...

- The 5th-level Sor/Wiz spell ***dragonsight*** [trans] (*SpC* 73) for 1 hour/level grants the caster, among other benefits, the ability to suffer only half the normal penalties for distance when making Spot skill checks. *Note:* Other spells reduce penalties *to attack rolls* for distance, which, while useful, doesn't actually help see stuff farther away. This spell does. Also see Custom Magic Items, below. Finally, this spell must be placed in a scepter or staff; its spell level precludes wanding.

## Improving Spot Skill Checks with Items

Most magic items granting bonuses to Spot skill checks grant competence bonuses. Nonetheless, some don't, so below I grouped items by bonus type then arranged items by price. Included are more interesting, obscure, and higher-bonus-providing items; omitted are many redundant or uninteresting items.

#### Alchemical Bonuses

- The alchemical item **prickly tea** (*Dragon* #301 54) (50 gp; 0 lbs.) for 1 hour grants the drinker, among other benefits, a +1 alchemical bonus to Spot skill checks.
- The religious equipment **mordrei'in** (*FE* 153) (25 gp; 0 lbs.) for 10 minutes grants the user, among other benefits, a +2 alchemical bonus to Spot skill checks. *Note:* Unique to the Eberron campaign setting. Also, it's a mild poison, so the user risks Constitution damage.

#### Circumstance Bonus

- The tool and skill kit item [**masterwork tool**](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/goodsAndServices.htm#toolMasterwork) (*PH* 129, 130-1) (50 gp; 1 lb.) for the skill Spot grants the user a +2 circumstance bonus to Spot skill checks.

#### Competence Bonuses

- The face slot item [***eyes of the eagle***](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#eyesoftheEagle)<sup>3</sup> (*DMG* 256) (2,500 gp; 0 lbs.) grant the wearer a +5 competence bonus to Spot skill checks. *Note:* Useful if restricted to core rules.
- The head slot item ***skullcap of eyes*** (*DrU* 101) (5,500 gp; 0 lbs.) grants the wearer, among other benefits, a +5 competence bonus to Spot skill checks.
- The face slot item ***third eye aware*** (*MIC* 140) (10,000 gp; 0 lbs.) grants the wearer a +10 competence bonus to Spot skill checks.
- The throat slot item ***dragon's eye amulet*** (*MIC* 95) (55,000 gp; 0 lbs.) grants the wearer, among other benefits, a +10 competence bonus to Spot skill checks.
- The armor/robe slot item [***robe of eyes***](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#robeofEyes) (*DMG* 265) (120,000 gp; 1 lb.) grants the wearer a +10 competence bonus to Spot skill checks. *Note:* Given the price, probably *not* useful if restricted to core.

#### Insight Bonus

- The face slot item ***crystal mask of insight*** (*MIC* 91) (20,000 gp; 0.5 lbs.) grants the wearer, among other benefits, a +9 insight bonus to Spot skill checks.

#### Profane Bonus

- The face slot items ***spider mask* (black widow)** and ***spider mask* (brown recluse)** (*Dragon* #298 47) (56,150 gp and 37,840 gp, respectively; 0 lbs.) grant the wearer, among other benefits, a +4 profane bonus to Spot skill checks. *Note:* Once donned, a *mask* is pretty much worn *permanently*. As a bonus, the *masks* look *horrifying*.

#### Unnamed Bonuses

- The alchemical item **hawk's ointment** (*CAd* 118, 119) (50 gp; 0 lbs.) for 2 minutes grants the user, among other benefits, a +1 bonus bonus to Spot skill checks. *Note:* Penalties apply after duration expires.
- The held item ***crystal anchor of alertness*** (*MIC* 155) (2,500 gp; 0.5 lbs.) grants the bearer the ability to take a standard action that leaves the item "planted in the ground" to grant for 1 hour 3/day allies within 30 ft., among other benefits, a +5 bonus to Spot skill checks. *Note:* Obviously for keeping watch, it'd be a useful item for *setting* ambushes were it not shedding light like a [lantern](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/exploration.htm#visionAndLight).
- The face slot item ***raptor's mask*** (*MIC* 210) (3,500 gp; 0 lbs.) grants the wearer, among other benefits, a +5 bonus to Spot skill checks. *Note:* If getting insight and competence bonuses to Spot skill checks from spells, this is what a creature wears.
- The face slot item ***goggles of draconic vision*** (*MIC* 107) (16,000 gp; 1 lbs.) grant the wearer, among other benefits, a +5 bonus to Spot skill checks.
- The head and half-face (i.e. the creature can wear, for example, a single lens) item ***eyes of the spider*** (*CSQ* 129) (212,000 gp; 0 lbs.) grants the wearer, among *significant* other benefits, a +4 bonus to Spot skill checks. *Note:* The wearer also probably looks like [Locutus of Borg](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/5653).

  [image: For the right character, it's kind of cool, I guess.]

### Custom Magic Items

A creature may be able to create--using Table 7-33: Estimating Magic Item Gold Piece Values (*DMG* 285)-- a custom item that grants a competence bonus to Spot skill checks of whatever bonus the creator wants. Such an item's cost to create, market price and prerequisites, however, are *exclusively* the DM's call, and the *first* thing the DM is supposed to consult when a creature crafts a custom item is a list of similar items. The list above *is* that list of similar items. That means while Table 7-33 says that the *goggles of spotting* (250,000 gp; 0.25 lbs.) that grant the wearer a +50 competence bonus to Spot checks is totally legit *in a vaccuum* or *if the DM's a goldfish*, such *goggles of spotting* are unlikely to keep those statistics--or even *exist*--in normal play with a normal DM despite Table 7-33. That's because Table 7-33 is the *last* place one goes for finding a magic item's special abilities, cost to create, market price, and prerequisites--not the first--, and most published non-epic magic items that grant skill bonuses top out at a +10 (usually named) bonus.

I believe enough items grant raw bonuses to Spot skill checks to render creating new ones unnecessary, but **a custom magic item granting the wearer the feat Hawk's Vision** (*CAd* 114)--*probably* a pair of goggles weighing 0 lbs. and *probably* costing 25,000 gp based on the *Arms and Equipment Guide*'s sidebar Magic Items that Grant Feats on page 128--is a good investment for the dedicated spotter. One of the feat's effects is to reduce the Spot check penalty for distance to -1 per *20 ft.* instead -1 per of 10 ft., effectively *doubling* the user's spotting range. However, unless the wearer possesses the supernatural ability *wild shape* (e.g. like a druid), the wearer must employ the skill Use Magic Device to emulate the class feature *wild shape* (probably of a druid unless the DM allows otherwise, therefore DC 25) then use the virtual class feature to activate the custom magic item like Lidda uses the class feature turn undead that she doesn't possess to activate nonetheless the magic chalice (*PH* 86). The DM, of course, has the final say how this process works; the skill Use Magic Device is a mine field.

## Combining Spells and Items

A creature *can* combine the different named and unnamed bonuses *spells* grant with the even more different named and unnamed bonuses *items* grant for a potentially *enormous* bonus to Spot skill checks, but bear in mind this will likely *greatly* annoy DMs who enjoy monsters surprising PCs.

---

1. I'm really *not* that crazy. A PC in one of my campaigns is using a homebrewed archer class with access to these spells, so I'd already done the research. That PC's bonus to Spot skill checks is *outrageous*.
2. The spell *vision of the omniscient eye* is *amazing*, and I urge creatures who can to add it to their spell books or spells known and those who can't to buy a wand of it and, if they've no wand in it already, put that wand in their primary weapon's wand chamber (*Du* 34) (100 gp; 0 lbs.).
3. In the *Dungeon Master's Guide* (2000) for *Dungeons and Dragons, 3rd Edition* the *eyes of the eagle* (*DMG* 216) (1,000 gp; 0 lbs.) and the *robe of eyes* (*DMG* 225) (90,000 gp; 1 lb.) granted much more interesting [circumstance bonuses](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/theBasics.htm#circumstanceModifier) to Spot skill checks (and the *robe* granted *+15*). These became [competence bonuses](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/theBasics.htm#competenceModifier) in *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* (and the *robe* dropped to +10).

Comment: Thank you very much for your awesome and very complete answer! What about a comparison with using @Andy's answer and have someone craft a "google of spot +50" for 250,000 gp? (or a cheaper combination, eg "+20 for 40,000gp")

Comment: @Epeedefeu You're welcome. I added a section on Custom Magic Items, but, honestly, they're a last resort (see text).

Comment: @Epeedefeu I'd have thought Google would be better for Search than Spot.

Comment: Is that a pun??

Comment: Our DM is quite open to magic item personalization. I am currently considering ordering lens of intelligence +6 (MIC says face is a natural slot for INT), with a spot competence bonus of +10 and a continuous spell effect of _eyes of the avoral_ (racial bonus to spot of +8) for a total bonus of INT+6, spot+18. I calculated separated prices as 36,000 + 10,000 + 3000 (1*1*2000*1.5), and since there are multiple abilities, I multiply the lower by 1.5, so that would reach 49,500 gp for the whole item. I will have to wait 50 days before it is finished to craft though.

Answer (score 7):

The Magic Item Compendium has a few. Some examples:

- *Third Eye Aware* (p. 140). Probably the item you're looking for if all you want is pure spotting. +10 competence bonus, nothing else. 10000gp.
- A *Raptor's Mask* (p. 210) is a decent face slot item. +5 untyped bonus on spot checks. "Also" renders the character immune to blindness and dazzling. 3500gp.
- *Eyes of Truth* (p. 99) are good eyes. +5 competence bonus to spot, and 1/day True Seeing for 1 round. 5500gp.
- The *Scout's Headband* (p. 133) grants a tiny spot bonus (+2 competence), but grants good vision-related enhancement by expending daily charges. 3400gp.
- The *Owlfeather Armor* (p. 20) is a good item. Provides a situational, non-permanent +5 competence bonus to spot checks. But, it lets you fly. 8160gp.
- The *Chronocharm of the Celestial Wanderer* (p. 85) allows you to reroll a listen or spot check each day. 500gp.

There are several others, but I believe these are most noteworthy.

Answer (score 4):

Check the Ioun Stone page: [Ioun Stone](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Ioun_Stone)

Dark Blue one will give you alertness (+2 on Listen and Spot)

Incandescent blue will give you a bonus to all Wisdom checks.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why no-one has mentioned "Eyes of the Eagle." They're on page 256 of the Dungeon Master's Guide, and offer a +5 competence bonus on Spot checks for only 2,500 gp.

Answer (score 3):

Custom Magic Item to enhance Spot cost bonus x bonus x 100 GP
[source](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/creatingMagicItems.htm#tableEstimatingMagicItemGoldPieceValues)

Comment: I wish I could accept your answer as well as @Ernir's. Thanks for the very interesting link, I think I am going to dig into that.

Answer (score -1):

Goggles of minute seeing could work if the spot checks are for traps/hidden doors/etc. you have to be within five feet for them to work though. -shrugs- it's a thought.

Comment: Don't those affect Search checks, and not Spot checks?

Comment: Yep, sorry about that. I didn't look into when I said this but if you hadn't brought it up I would have sworn they were for search and spot, apologies